# What is the last column on the scoreboard before players' items?

Tags: paragon

There are 5 columns on the scoreboard in Paragon. From playing other MOBA games, I've figured out what 4 of them represent, but the last eludes me. The first four are kills, deaths, assists, and number of minions killed.

The last one starts at 0 for each player, and seems to only be able to be a multiple of 10. I've seen people end the match still at 0, and I've seen people go over 1000 in that column. I've personally had games where my score has been both low and high, but I can't figure out what was different between them.

What does this column represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the accumulative total of Card XP (CXP) that that player has earned for your team.

According to [this forum post](https://www.epicgames.com/paragon/forums/showthread.php?6726-Scoreboard-last-column#post_0), killing towers/inhibitors, and using harvesters will contribute to global CXP, increasing the total in the 5th column.

It doesn't include your individual CXP, earned from minions and enemy heroes, however. So that total is strictly the global CXP.